# what type of a c# project to choose for creating a telegram bot

Tags: c#, visual-studio, telegram-bot

I am starting to learn how to make a telegram bot.I want to do it using c#. but i dont know what type of a project to create for that in visual studio. [these are the options when i choose c# project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdD9z.png)

Answer (score 3):

You can select Windows->C#->Console Application

That's all, that you need to write you Telegram Bot. After that - go to nuget packages and download Telegram.Bot library and you're ready!